# Expected number of events at a neutrino telescope

Tags: particle-physics, scattering-cross-section

When you want to detect neutrinos from an isotropic neutrino sources like a supernova, how can you calculate the number of events?

For simplification let's assume the neutrino flux is mono-energetic. Then according to section 1.2 of the paper [Neutrinos as astrophysical probes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0311256.pdf) the expected number of neutrino events at a neutrino telescope is
$$
N_{events} = \Phi_{\nu} \times \sigma_{\nu}\times N_{targets} \times t
$$
where $\Phi_{\nu}$ is neutrino flux, $\sigma_{\nu}$ is cross section of the neutrino, and $t$ is the detector lifetime.

Could one please answer

- (1) if that's a valid calculation, and
- (2) how is equation derived?

The equation implies that $N_{events}$ does not depend on the shape and volume of the detector. To me it looks strange.

Comment: A neutrino interacts with single nuclei, without any knowledge of other nuclei. How would the collective shape and size of the whole detector matter?

Comment: I wondered if one doesn't have to know, for example, the effective area of the detector.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Cross sectional area matters if the flux is being attenuated in the detector medium, which is not the case for neutrinos.

Comment: *"The equation implies that $N_{events}$ does not depend on the shape and volume of the detector."* $N_\text{targets}$ is the size dependence. "Target" means a nucleon for which the proposed interaction is over-threshold.

Answer (score 5):

The paper does *not* say that this is the number of detected events, it says that the "number of events scales as". Whether it is exact depends on how you specify the flux and the cross-section.

If the cross-section is in units of $m^2$ per "target" (nucleus) in the detector and the flux is numbers of neutrinos per square metre per unit time, then the equation is correct (assuming that every interaction is detected).

The reason the detector shape is unimportant is that the neutrino flux can be considered uniform across the detector and the chance of any individual neutrino interacting with a "target" is very, very small. There is no sense in which one target could be "hidden" behind another target (which is why geometry matters if the chance of an interaction within the detector approaches unity).

The detector volume *is* important, since for a detector material of fixed density, then $N_{\rm targets}$ is proportional to the detector volume.